Taylor series approximation of a vector-valued function around specific value of another function
I have two vector-valued functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. I need to find the first two terms of Taylor expansion of $f$ around $g(\overline{x}_0)$. Something like this:
$$f(\overline{x})\approx f(\overline{x}_0)+\nabla f(g(\overline{x}_0))(g(\overline{x})-g(\overline{x}_0))$$
I know what I wrote above is not correct. Is something like this even possible?

The notation $\nabla f(g(\bar x_0))$ seems a bit confusing. Since $g(\bar x_0)\in\Bbb R$, why can we put it into $\nabla f$ which only accepts its variable from $\Bbb R^n$?
